# MvxPickerViewModel Bind to Property of an Object

Tags: xamarin.ios, uipickerview, mvvmcross

I have following code:

```
var pickerViewModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(this.mandantenPicker);
this.mandantenPicker.Model = pickerViewModel;
this.mandantenPicker.ShowSelectionIndicator = true;
mandantenAuswahlTextfield.InputView = this.mandantenPicker;

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();

set.Bind(pickerViewModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedMandant);
set.Bind(pickerViewModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Mandanten);

set.Apply();
```

In the PickerView I don't have the expected values. Its showing the namespace of the object.

I'm binding to a list of "Mandants", a Mandant has FirstName/LastName. How can I set the "to be showed" value?

So something like:

```
set.Bind(pickerViewModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Mandanten)["FirstName"]; //stupid example but to show better what I mean/want
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MvxPickerViewModel currently uses `GetTitle()` to work out what to display:

```
    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView picker, int row, int component)
    {
        return _itemsSource == null ? "-" : RowTitle(row, _itemsSource.ElementAt(row));
    }

    protected virtual string RowTitle(int row, object item)
    {
        return item.ToString();
    }
```

from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxPickerViewModel.cs

If you wanted to customise the strings displayed, you could:

- inherit from MvxPickerViewModel and provide an override for `RowTitle`:

  ```
  protected override string RowTitle(int row, object item)
  {
      return ((Mandant)item).FirstName;
  }
  ```
- or override the `ToString` in your `Mandant` object
- or provide and use some ValueConverters from `IEnumerable<Mandant>` to `IEnumerable<WrappedMandant>` and `Mandant` to `WrappedMandant` where `WrappedMandant`  provides the `ToString()` implementation you want to use:

  ```
    public class WrappedMandant
    {
         public Mandant Mandant { get;set;}
         public override string ToString()
         {
             return Mandant.FirstName;
         }
    }
  ```

If you wanted to customise the picker cells displayed further, then you could also override `GetView` and them provide a custom cell for each `Mandant`